# A topos where every object is internally projective but not every object is projective

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

An object $P$ in a topos $\mathcal{E}$ is said to be projective if $Hom_{\mathcal{E}}(p,-)$ preserves epis,  internally projective if $(-)^P$ preserves epis.

Can anyone give an example of a topos where every object is internally projective but not every object is projective? Can such a topos be a presheaf topos? Generally what properties for $\mathbf{C}$ such that $\mathbf{Sets}^{\mathbf{C}}$ is such a presheaf topos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Johnstone's *Sketches of an Elephant*, section D.4.5 for the following and more examples.

If $G$ is a group, then the topos of $G$-sets satisfies the internal axiom of choice -- every object is internally projective. But the only projective objects are the free $G$-sets. So if $G$ is nontrivial, then this topos does not have every object projective -- it does not satisfy the external axiom of choice.

Comment: Could you summarise generally what properties for $C$ making the presheaf topos  $Sets^C$ satisfying IAC but not AC?

Comment: You need $C$ to be a groupoid for $Sets^C$ to satisfies IAC and $C$ to be (equivalent to) a set for $Set^C$ to satisfies external choice.

Comment: @SimonHenry Do you mean $C$ has to be equivalent to the category $Sets$ to satisfy external choice?

Comment: No: to a set. I.e a discrete category